# Writing formulas with Python Doxygen

Tags: python, latex, doxygen

I am trying to write a formula into the doxygen output file using the latest version of doxygen (1.8.14). 
I tried:

```
#  @f$(@sum_{sc=1}^{3} @sum_{n=1}^{24} pENSCost * ENS_sc,n)@f$
```

But doing so does not give me the desired output, but instead of the sigmas (the sum sign) it just gives me `@sum` , even though with the desired indices, but I don´t get any error messages. Does anybody know what I did wrong?

Comment: Please show a bit more  of the surrounding of the formula (i.e. something that can be reproduced. Which version of doxygen are you using? Did you get a warning  when running doxygen ? Looks like the closing tag of the formula is missing.

Comment: You were right, the closing tag was missing. I adjusted the Problem.

Comment: shouldn't @sum be \sum in LaTeX? (inside the formula tags the text is LaTeX code not doxygen comment).

Comment: You´re right! When I read how to document in Python that the backslash wouldn´t work out of a reason I don´t remember, but as it seems this was not the case. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had 2 problems in this case:

- initially the `@f$` closing tag iof the formula was missing (corrected in the question)
- the formula contained `@sum` but the content of the formula has the contain LaTeX commands and not doxygen commands and thus the `@sum` should be `\sum`.